# After adding ads in my flutter appliation my application is getting crash on initializiation when internet is off

Tags: android, flutter, dart

This is main function : Where i have initialized my AdmobService and later in the other widget I am showing ad using Adwidget.

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  AdMobService.initialize();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
  runApp(
    const MyApp(),
  );
}
```

This is My AdmobService class :

```
class AdMobService {
  InterstitialAd? _interstitialAd;
  BannerAd? _bannerAd;
  static String get bannerAdUnitId => Platform.isAndroid
      ? "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
      : "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";

  static initialize() {
    if (MobileAds.instance == null) {
      MobileAds.instance.initialize();
    }
  }

  bool createbannerAd() {
    _bannerAd = BannerAd(
      adUnitId: bannerAdUnitId,
      size: AdSize.smartBanner,
      request: AdRequest(),
      listener: BannerAdListener(
          onAdLoaded: (Ad ad) => print("Ad loaded"),
          onAdFailedToLoad: (Ad ad, LoadAdError error) {
            _bannerAd = null;
            ad.dispose();
          },
          onAdOpened: (Ad ad) => print("Ad opened"),
          onAdClosed: (Ad ad) => print("Ad closed")),
    );
    if (_bannerAd == null) {
      return false;
    } else {
      _bannerAd!.load();
      return true;
    }

   
  }

  BannerAd? showbannerAd() {
    return _bannerAd;
  }
}
```

Before adding the Ads app was working fine but after adding ads it crashes if internet is off and works fine if interner is on.

Comment: It doesn't sound logic to you that you should check if the user has internet before proceeding to show ads?

Comment: Please share your crash logs. So it will be more specific to find out real problem.